# how to stop to call the same function again and again in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is the HTML code, while clicking on clearfix class function called will happen and it will run the same function 4 times .

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <ul id="dashboard-tab" class="nav nav-tabs pull-left">
        <li class="active" isdashboardloaded="true">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard_5" aria-expanded="true">DashLoadingLineChart</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" isdashboardloaded="true">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard_6" aria-expanded="false">Zoom</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS function

```
$(document).on('click','.clearfix',function(){
    var dashId=$('.dashboardTabContent.active').attr('id');
    var dash_ids = bu.angular.pageScope.dashboardCollection.collection;
    var dashBoardUrl=event.target.href;
    $.each(dashObj.widgetObj,function(widgetId,widgetObj){
        clearWidget(widgetId,widgetObj.mode);
        var widget_refresh_interval = widgetObj.refresh_interval;
        //widgetInterval[widgetId] = 0;
        clearInterval(widgetInterval[widgetId]);
        bu.angular.pageScope.$digest();
        widgetWiseReload(widgetId,dashId)
        getWidgetData(widgetId,dashId,widgetObj,data_sources);
    });
});
```

i need to run this function only one time, but it is running more than 2 times .

Comment: So you're putting someting in a loop and are wondering why the loop actually runs?

Comment: Use [`$.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/). This will attach the handler and  is executed at most once per element per event type.

Comment: @baao, after complete the loop it will come back again to same function .

Comment: @Pugazh, i tried $(id).once('click',function(){ ..... }), its not working according to condition . that html will create tabs like DashLoadingLineChart and zoom , if i am clicking to zoom tab , that function will run 4 times .

Comment: @Illusion please check the answer given by Jorge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are attaching the function more than one time. Try this:

```
$(document).off("click", ".clearfix").on('click','.clearfix',function() {
    $.each(dashObj.widgetObj,function(widgetId,widgetObj){
        clearWidget(widgetId,widgetObj.mode);
        var widget_refresh_interval = widgetObj.refresh_interval;
        //widgetInterval[widgetId] = 0;
        clearInterval(widgetInterval[widgetId]);
        bu.angular.pageScope.$digest();
        widgetWiseReload(widgetId,dashId)
        getWidgetData(widgetId,dashId,widgetObj,data_sources);
    });
});
```

This will detach the event before attaching it again, so if is called more than one time, it will be attached one time, actually.

Protip: Keep your indentation clean.

Protip 2: If this was the problem, then you should look why this code is called more than one time instead of using this hack.

Comment: function createTableWidget(data,errorStatus,callbackDataUI){......................

Comment: can i use the same above code for this also beacuse i am invoking this function -->  function createTableWidget(data,errorStatus,callbackDataUI){.........} , and  function running more than one time .

Comment: @Illusion This is a dirty patch and, as I already stated, you have to check why that part of the code is being called more than one time. If you only add dirty patches you will end up with a dirty broken code. If you fix the root, then you won't face again the "running multiple times" problem. Check where is that function called, and check the parent,  and the parent, and such. Also, add `debugger;` lines so the browser stops and you can check where it comes from. You need to learn to use the Developer Tools (F12). They are really important for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
// define a function of runOce
function runOnce(fn) {
  var isDone = false;
  return function(){
    if(isDone){
      return;
    }
    isDone = true;
    fn();
  };
}

// demo
function youWantRunFn(){
  alert(0);
}
var changeYourFn = runOnce(youWantRunFn);
// now,changeYourFn only can run once
changeYourFn(); // alert 0
changeYourFn(); // nothing
```